# Bootstrap input not aligning

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, input, prepend

I am trying to prepend to one of my inputs but my problem is that the prepend doesn't fall into the right place

This is what it looks like:
https://prnt.sc/l7wf9y

This is my html:

```
<div class="form-group"> <label>Avsändare</label> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sender_input"> </div>
            <div class="form-group"> <label>Mottagare</label> <div class="input-group-prepend">
<span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-default">Default</span>
```

Meddelande:

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gcbL1e0a/2/

Comment: please insert the image directly here instead of posting a link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: `input-group-prepend` just works inside `input-group`.

Modify your code like the following ([working fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/gcbL1e0a/8/)):

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Mottagare</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-default">Default</span>
        </div>
        <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="+46000000000" id="recipient_input">
     </div>
</div>
```

This results in:

[image]